# Lagrange Interpolation for a schema based on Shamir's Secret Sharing

Tags: haskell, cryptography, interpolation, polynomials

I'm trying to debug an issue with an implementation of a threshold encryption scheme. I've posted [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/54790/baek-and-zheng-s-threshold-cryptosystem-limit-on-threshold) on crypto to get some help with the actual scheme but was hoping to get a sanity check on the simplified code I am using.

Essentially the the crypto system uses Shamir's Secret Sharing to combine the shares of a key. The polynomial is each member of the list 'a' multiplied by a increasing power of the parameter of the polynomial. I've left out the mod by prime to simplify the code as the actual implementation uses PBC via a Haskell wrapper.

I have for the polynomial

```
poly :: [Integer] -> Integer -> Integer
poly as xi = (f 1 as)
  where
    f _ [] = 0
    f 0 _ = 0
    f s (a:as) = (a * s) + f (s * xi) as
```

The Lagrange interpolation is:

```
interp0 :: [(Integer, Integer)] -> Integer
interp0 xys = round (sum $ zipWith (*) ys $ fmap (f xs) xs)
  where
    xs = map (fromIntegral .fst) xys
    ys = map (fromIntegral .snd) xys

f :: (Eq a, Fractional a) => [a] -> a -> a
f xs xj = product $ map (p xj) xs

p :: (Eq a, Fractional a) => a -> a -> a
p xj xm = if xj == xm then 1 else negate (xm / (xj - xm))
```

and the split and combination code is

```
execPoly as@(a0:_) = do
  let xs = zipWith (,) [0..] (fmap (poly as) [0..100])
  let t = length as + 1
  let offset = 1
  let shares = take t (drop offset xs)
  let sm2 = interp0 shares
  putText ("poly and interp over " <> show as <> " = " <> show sm2 <> ". Should be " <> show a0)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  execPoly [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150] --1
  execPoly [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80] -- 2
```

execPoly(1) fails to combine to 10 but execPoly(2) combines correctly. The magic threshold seems to be 8.

Is my code correct? I am missing something in the implementation that limits the threshold size to 8?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code. My best guess would be that this is some kind of numeric precision problem. Try dumping out intermediate values to see if they are what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MathematicalOrchid said it was a precision problem.

Updated the code to:

```
f :: (Eq a, Integral a) => [a] -> a -> Ratio a
f xs xj = product $ map (p xj) xs

p :: (Eq a, Integral a)=> a -> a -> Ratio a
p xj xm = if xj == xm then (1 % 1) else (negate xm) % (xj - xm)
```

And it works as expected.